# Xamarin Forms - Working with SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have been trying to follow this video to learn working with SQLite in Xamarin Forms and I am stuck

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FVH-9zjRP9M

project.Droid

```
class LocalDatabaseHelper : Classes.ILocalDatabaseHelper
{
    public string GetLocalFilePath(string fileName)
    {
        string docFolder = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
        string libFolder = Path.Combine(docFolder, "..", "Library", "Databases");

        if (!Directory.Exists(libFolder))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(libFolder);
        }
        return Path.Combine(libFolder, fileName);
    }
}
```

project (pcl)

```
    public static Classes.TaskReminder.TaskReminderDatabaseOperation Database
    {
        get
        {
            if (database == null)
            {
                string LocalFilePath = "";
                if(Device.OS==TargetPlatform.Android)
                {
                    LocalFilePath = DependencyService.Get<Classes.ILocalDatabaseHelper>().GetLocalFilePath("TaskReminder.db3");
                }
                database = new Classes.TaskReminder.TaskReminderDatabaseOperation(LocalFilePath);
            }
            return database;
        }
    }

public interface ILocalDatabaseHelper
{
    string GetLocalFilePath(string fileName);
}
```

And it is giving me Unhandled exception when executing

```
LocalFilePath = DependencyService.Get<Classes.ILocalDatabaseHelper>().GetLocalFilePath("TaskReminder.db3");
```

please help. thanks in advance.

**NOTE (more information):**

project (PCL)

```
public class TaskReminderDatabaseOperation
    {
        readonly SQLiteAsyncConnection database;
        public TaskReminderDatabaseOperation(string dbPath)
        {
            database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
            database.CreateTableAsync<TaskReminder>().Wait();
        }

        public Task<List<TaskReminder>> GetTaskRemindersAsync()
        {
            return database.Table<TaskReminder>().ToListAsync();
        }

        public Task<TaskReminder> GetTaskReminder(DateTime datetime)
        {
            return database.Table<TaskReminder>().Where(i => i.ReminderDateTime == datetime).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
        }

        public Task<int> SaveTaskReminder(TaskReminder taskReminder)
        {
            if (taskReminder.Id == 0)
            {
                return database.InsertAsync(taskReminder);
            }
            else
            {
                return database.UpdateAsync(taskReminder);
            }
        }

        public Task<int> DeleteTaskReminder(TaskReminder taskReminder)
        {
            return database.DeleteAsync(taskReminder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the exception? And how is your adorn to the LocalDatabaseHelper?

Comment: An unhandled exception occured. occurred

Comment: do you have the correct DependencyService attribute in your LocalDatabaseHelper?

Comment: use try/catch to catch the Exception and figure out exactly what is causing it.

Comment: @Jason it is showing nullreferenceexception.. does that mean my GetLocalFilePath() is returning null? or does that mean the system cant find the GetLocalFilePath() method?

Comment: Most likely - as I said, you need to be sure your DependencyService is decorated with the correct attributes.  See: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/#Registration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look closely at the video, around [29 minutes and 10 seconds](https://youtu.be/FVH-9zjRP9M?t=29m10s). You will see that he adds a attribute to the project class.  This registers the dependency with the [Dependency Service](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction/#Registration) in Xamarin.Forms.

You probably forgot to do that, that is why you will get a `NullReferenceException` when you try to resolve the implementation of the interface.

Please look into the workings of the Dependency Service to understand how these kinds of things work and resolve these errors for yourself, instead of just following the video.